# Erro PLS-00103 ao tentar compilar um Package

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

estou tentando compilar o package abaixo e está sendo retornado o erro: Erro(9,3): PLS-00103: Encontrado o símbolo "BEGIN" quando um dos seguintes símbolos era esperado:     idioma

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PCK_TB_ESTADO
IS
  PROCEDURE PRC_INSERE
  (P_NM_REDE_FUNCIONARIO IN TB_FUNCIONARIO.NM_REDE_FUNCIONARIO%TYPE,
  P_DS_ESTADO IN TB_ESTADO.DS_ESTADO%TYPE,
  P_ID_UF IN TB_ESTADO.ID_UF,
  P_MENS OUT VARCHAR2)
  IS
  BEGIN
    CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ESTADO
      MINVALUE 1
      MAXVALUE 99
      START WITH 1
      INCREMENT BY 1;
    INSERT INTO TB_ESTADO
    VALUES (SEQ_ESTADO.NEXTVAL,P_DS_ESTADO,P_ID_UF,SYSDATE,P_NM_REDE_FUNCIONARIO);
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        P_MENS := 'Você tentou executar um comando INSERT ou UPDATE que criou um valor duplicado em um campo restrito por um index único.';
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        P_MENS := 'Erro.';
  END;
END PCK_TB_ESTADO;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Packages*** no Oracle são divididos em especificação (*specification*) e implementação (*body*).

A implementação das procedures e funções, além de declarações de variáveis, devem ser feitas usando o comando [`CREATE PACKAGE BODY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_package_body.htm#LNPLS01372).

Um exemplo, extraído [de outra documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg10pck.htm):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Emp_package AS
    TYPE Emp_data_type IS RECORD (
        Emp_number NUMBER,
        Hire_date  VARCHAR2(12),
        Emp_name   VARCHAR2(10));
    PROCEDURE Get_emp_data
        (Emp_data IN OUT Emp_data_type);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Emp_package AS
    PROCEDURE Get_emp_data
        (Emp_data IN OUT Emp_data_type) IS
   BEGIN
       SELECT Empno, Ename, TO_CHAR(Hiredate, 'DD/MON/YY')
           INTO Emp_data
           FROM Emp_tab
           WHERE Empno = Emp_data.Emp_number;
   END;
END;
```

### Notas sobre a procedure da pergunta

A criação de uma sequência de auto-incremento dentro da procedure provavelmente não vai surtir o efeito que você quer por dois motivos:

1. Um objeto não pode ser usado no mesmo bloco que foi criado, pois o Oracle faz a criação de uma forma transacional. Pelo menos nas versões que eu uso, esse código não vai nem compilar. Porém, você pode usar o comando [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm) para forçar a execução e alteração imediata.
2. Mesmo criando o `SEQUENCE` com sucesso, ele sempre iria iniciar com o mesmo valor. Por que simplesmente não o cria juntamente com a tabela, uma única vez?